# how to split tuple and assign to new variables python

Tags: python

I have the following code to get a shapefile's layer extent in python which prints the extent as `(317044.25, 322287.25, 681703.75, 685053.25)`

```
from osgeo import ogr

# Get a Layer's Extent
inShapefile = "c:/shapefile.shp"
inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
inDataSource = inDriver.Open(inShapefile, 0)
inLayer = inDataSource.GetLayer()
extent = inLayer.GetExtent()
featureCount = inLayer.GetFeatureCount()

print(extent)
```

I'd now like to do a few things to this tuple:

- Separate them into 2 new variables
- Remove the decimal places
- Remove the brackets

Therefore leaving my results as follows:

```
extent1 = 317044, 322287
extent2 = 681703, 685053
```

I've tried the following code to split the tuple, but can't figure out how to assign to new variables and do the other requirements

```
# tuple into 2 tuples
res = tuple(extent[x:x + 2] 
      for x in range(0, len(extent), 2))
  
# printing result
print (str(res))
```

Comment: `extent1 = 317044 322287` is not a valid ... thing in Python.

Comment: Are you sure that it's a `tuple`, can you give us `print(type(extent))`?

Comment: The result was ```<class 'tuple'>```

Comment: What type do you expect your `extent1` and `extent2` to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Separating [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-tuples)s into variables**

[Sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#:%7E:text=called%2C%20appropriately%20enough%2C-,sequence%20unpacking,-and%20works%20for) and [tuple packing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#:%7E:text=an%20example%20of-,tuple%20packing,-%3A%20the%20values%2012345)?

```py
from osgeo import ogr

## Get a Layer's Extent
inShapefile = "c:/shapefile.shp"
inDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
inDataSource = inDriver.Open(inShapefile, 0)
inLayer = inDataSource.GetLayer()

## Unpack
x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = inLayer.GetExtent()
# (317044.25, 322287.25, 681703.75, 685053.25)

## Pack
extent1 = x_min, x_max
# (317044.25, 322287.25)
extent2 = y_min, y_max
# (681703.75, 685053.25)
```

**Removing decimal place**

If you want to round the floats, you can wrap the variables in [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

```py
extent1 = int(x_min), int(x_max)
# (317044, 322287)
extent2 = int(y_min), int(y_max)
# (681703, 685053)
```

You can also use [`round(x[, n])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round), [`math.floor(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor), [`math.ceil(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) depending on what your needs are.

P.S. You may examples from [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html) of use.

**Removing brackets**

My hunch is you may be mistaking these [tuple / sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) operations for string outputs. I don't believe you intend to be doing this.

However, lets say you really wanted to coalesce a tuple like `(317044, 322287)` into a [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) object that printed like `317044 322287`:

```py
extent1_str = " ".join([str(item) for item in extent1])
# '317044 322287'
extent2_str = " ".join([str(item) for item in extent2])
# '681703 685053'
```

For future reference, we'd say `"317044 322287"` (in single or double quotes) which would imply we're referring to [textual data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#textseq) (aka "string literal"). These look like magic, but in reality they're computed by ["dunder"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=dunder#:%7E:text=System%2Ddefined%20names%2C%20informally%20known%20as%20%E2%80%9Cdunder%E2%80%9D%20names.) methods on the object: [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Answer (score 0):

The question is bit unclear, But I assume that you want to convert decimle to integer and assign it to two varibles
Hers's the code that might solve your problem.

```
extent=(317044.25, 322287.25, 681703.75, 685053.25)
extent = list(map(int,extent))

extent1=extent[:2]
extent2=extent[2:]

print(extent1,extent2)
```

The output:

```
[317044, 322287] [681703, 685053]
```

To print according to your requirement:

```
print('extent1 = {},{}'.format(extent1[0],extent1[1]))
print('extent2 = {},{}'.format(extent2[0],extent2[1]))
```

Output:

```
extent1 = 317044,322287
extent2 = 681703,685053
```